# FICO score reporting variation

Tags: credit-card, fico-score

Why `FICO` score vary between credit companies?
I have two credit cards and each lender is proving me with a different score, there is a difference of 5 points, not that big difference, but what is the reason behind it?

Comment: It also depends on which of the 3 agencies reports are used to calculate the score. Some cards are not even real fico scores but internal or not widely used scores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timing of the reports can be different, the weightings of information on the report can be different, and the scale itself can be different as there are variations of the FICO scores, and variations of which FICO reporting company the credit card system is using. These are the differences.

Your credit worthiness should still be apparent, as it isn't that nuanced.